# How can I cancel a pending transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, security

https://blockchain.info/tx/d2aa8e971dd26a4f4598f57b55e921a62fa376dad1cf25e426b6ba7d79052466?show_adv=true. This transaction was made by some fraudsters on my wallet. I later recovered my wallet. How can I cancel this transaction [image]

Comment: You can't "cancel" a transaction sent from a web wallet, and RBF/double-spend is also not possible from web wallet. 
There is nothing you can do, your funds are lost.

Actutally there is one thing you can try, there is a slim chance that this might work though.
[Export your private keys](http://bl4nkcode.info/bitcoin/how_to_export_blockchain_wallet_private_key) to Electrum and report back if the transaction and addresses show up in Electrum wallet.

Comment: It shows low fee

Comment: What? Do the transaction and addresses show up in Electrum?

Comment: Yes It does, every transaction I've done

Comment: Since the transaction is still unconfirmed, are you able to double spend from 1EmKvWN4NYs3Sx7WNz8ur44wpKqWRn1Gtj and 15tdaQ2vJpcJLFrYTW7QQJDmg4Nz9UhBUE to yourself? Here is [a step-by-step](https://steemit.com/bitcoin/@profitgenerator/tutorial-how-to-fix-unconfirmed-transactions) . If this is possible, then you may be able to send the funds to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cancel an unconfirmed transaction if RBF (replace-by-fee) enabled for this transaction you could replace the fee. but I guess you are using blockchain.info wallet which is not possible there.

What you can do is asking the receiver to send this transaction to another receiver with double fee. so the transaction gets confirmed.

or you can try to push this transaction manually.

Comment: Thetransaction was done illegally by some fraudsters